# deserialize using Play framework ScalaJsonGenerics vs Jerkson

Tags: json, playframework

I seem to be confused when using the play framework on how to deserialize json correctly.  With jerkson it looks like you just have to define a case class which then automatically deserializes a json string (stolen from the jerkson docs).

```
case class Person(id: Long, name: String)
parse[Person]("""{"id":1,"name":"Coda"}""") //=> Person(1,"Coda")
```

But, with play framework you have to write a lot of boiler plate code to do the same thing.  For instance from their documentation.

```
case class Foo(name: String, entry: Int) 

object Foo {
  implicit object FopReads extends Format[Foo] {
    def reads(json: JsValue) = Foo(
      (json \ "name").as[String],
      (json \ "entry").as[Int])
    def writes(ts: Foo) = JsObject(Seq(
      "name" -> JsString(ts.name),
      "entry" -> JsNumber(ts.entry)))
    }
 }
```

This seems like a lot more work, so i assume i'm either not using it correctly or don't quite understand the advantage of doing it this way. Is there a short cut so that I don't have to write all of this code?  If not, should I just be using jerkson in my Action to parse a incoming json string?  It seems as though asText is returning a blank string, even when asJson works just fine...which leads me to believe I am definitely doing something wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Does anyone know this one?  I did something ghetto and just mixed the two concepts like this `def reads(json: JsValue) = Json.parse[Cacheref](json.toString)`.  Seems like it can't possibly be correct

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two answers to your question.

1. For somewhat less boiler plate, you can use the the Play support for handling case classes.  Here's an example for a case class with three fields:

   implicit val SampleSetFormat: Format[SampleSet] = productFormat3("sensorId", "times", "values")(SampleSet)(SampleSet.unapply)
2. I agree that there is more annoying boiler plate, the main reason the Play folks seem to use this approach so they can determine the correct serializer entirely at compile time.  So no cost of reflecting as in Jerkson.

Comment: Is there any way to use the productFormat function only for reading? I usually have a plain representation when reading, but when I write back the JSON I often need to include related models

Answer (score 0):

I am a total noob with Play and Jerkson, but wholeheartedly recommend doing the least boilerplate approach (using Jerkson lib within each Action).  I find that it is philosophically more in line with Scala to do so and it works fine.